# What type of plot is this in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, seaborn, data-science

I was reading a paper, and I stumbled against the picture below. Roughly speaking, blue and orange dots represent a data set for classification. The decision boundary is the white line. The key feature of the picture is that the rest of the points in the plane are colored according to the value of a specific function(see the values of the function to the right). Since I would like to reproduce the results of that paper, it would be nice if could plot some picture like that. Hence, the question:

What is the name of this type of plot?[image]

Comment: This would be a "filled contour plot with scatter points on top and a white line".

Comment: Where does stack overflow occur? Would you ask this question at: https://stats.stackexchange.com/